# Tiny bug with suspension

Tags: feature-request, bug, accepted-answer, account-suspension

First off, this is a very tiny bug that doesn't really affect anything here except my perfectionism.

When a suspended user tries to accept an answer on **their** question, the following message comes up:

> Suspended user cannot **vote**

I believe this should read

> Suspended users cannot **accept answers**

Comment: Accepts are a type of vote, so this is *technically* correct, even if it's not what you'd expect.

Comment: Avoid getting suspended then.